# Spring Data JPA NamedStoredProcedureQuery out Multiple tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping, entitygraph

```
I am using JDK17 and spring-boot 3.0.7
```

When I am trying to return the data in multiple tables from a short proc getting an exception for a column, looks to me like hibernate is not able to map multiple out.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
name = Car.FIND_STATUS,
resultClasses = {CarChoices.class, CarMake.class, CarHistory.class, CarExpenses.class},
procedureName = "dealer.find_cars",
parameters = {
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = CarChoices.CAR_NUMBER, type = String.class)
        }
)

@Entity
public class CarChoices {

    public static final String FIND_STATUS = "findStatusOfCar";
    public static final String CAR_NUMBER = "car_numbers";
    public static final int CAR_NUMBER_PARAM_LENGTH = 300;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "car_number")
    private String carNumber;

    @Column(name = "car_status_code")
    private String statusCode;

    @Column(name = "car_status_en")
    private String statusEnglish;

    @Column(name = "car_status_fr")
    private String statusFrench;

    @Column(name = "car_office_en")
    private String officeEnglish;

    @Column(name = "car_office_fr")
    private String officeFrench;

    @Column(name = "car_registration_date")
    private LocalDate registrationDate;

    @Transient
    private CarMake carMake;

    @Transient
    private Set<CarHistory> carHistory = new TreeSet<>();

    @Transient
    private Set<CarExpenses> carExpenses = new TreeSet<>();

    //Getter and Setter

}
```

I am getting an exception when calling the short proc 'dealer.find_cars'

[Exception on Run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSnMD.png)

column 'service_address_1' comes in CarHistory.class

I am expecting read all the data by hibernate